# Why there is no donation page on Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, design, donation

I am an Movies & TV SE user.

Why there is no donation page on Stack Exchange?

With donations, the SE communities could make the site design even more beautiful.

Comment: Sorry, but how would a donation page help with designs exactly? The Stack Exchange designers are employees of Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't think Stack Exchange is in need of donations. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/

Comment: If instead you are thinking that giving money for answers will help, please think again. People give answers right now to share their knowledge, if you start putting in money they motivations change drastically and you'll get very different answers.

Comment: `Why there is no donation page on Stack Exchange?` Simple ,not needed. `With donations, the SE communities could make the site design even more beautiful` please site an example ?(How would donations help the community designs better)

Answer (score 5):

It's been said before, and I'll say it again:

The best way to donate to Stack Exchange is with your time, by posting, editing, and moderating content.

As other people have said, it's a business, and in addition to ad and Careers revenue, it is also [VC-funded](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/). There are something like two hundred employees who make a living working at Stack Exchange Inc., but none of the system would be possible without users contributing their time to do those three aforementioned tasks.

As for the designs, I personally take no issue in them, but also as others have mentioned, if you would like something altered, you should post on that site's Meta asking for it. If the community agrees, and if it doesn't break compatibility with any obscure browsers that need to be supported, and if the aforementioned employees consider it to be a priority over designing and maintaining other sites' appearances, there's a good chance that it'll get done.

But to reiterate, if you want Stack Exchange to be successful, there is a very necessary component that costs only your time and expertise, and sometimes not even all that much of the latter. As you begin to climb in [reputation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you'll begin to earn [privileges](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), like the ability to vote, edit freely, engage in discussions on Meta and in chat, and even vote to close questions. At each of those privilege levels, you'll learn a new way that you can contribute to the community, and in turn the business, in a meaningful way.

The first step to beginning that process is to review the standards of other questions, and read posts here on Meta Stack Exchange, and the meta of the site (presumably Movies) whose community you'd like to join, to understand the philosophy and central workings of the Stack Exchange system. Read help articles, ask questions in constructive ways, and you'll quickly find what makes the Q&A system here work. Once you do that, you'll likely find that contributing and gaining reputation will become much easier and more natural.

If money is your primary concern (and it sure doesn't seem to be Stack Exchange's, from what we hear in the podcasts and read on the blog), you can consider that those tasks are what make the communities thrive, which is what brings on more users and shows potential investors and employers (potential Careers clients, that is) that there's clearly something good going on here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no use. Stack Exchange is a company, not a non profit organisation in desperate need of help.

SE has its own way of making money, through adds for example, and the Careers site. Donations are not a part of the business plan.

If you don't like the page design, post a question on the site meta. Make sure it is constructive, and not a rant. Be aware that [Jin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin) will personally track you down ;).

Answer (score 1):

Purpose is not to take money; the purpose is improving SE. *The following things could require large funding*; and it won't be very wrong if a part for that comes as donation.

- 1. Increase the *server strength*, and avoid server [**crash or jam**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289621/why-could-stack-exchange-block-someone-just-for-visiting-64-or-more-tags-on-tago).
- 2. Increase the *memory space* to safely host more question-answers.
- 3. Evolving multiple, powerful sync and back-up networks, at different part of world;  so that if the data in the site get damaged anyhow; the sync and back-up network will recover it.
- 4. Installing more *long-lasting* and *good-quality* *hardwares*.
- 5. Better *troubleshooting* and *hardware repairing*.
- 6. Better *feature-update* and *support service.*
- 7. Better *maintenance* of all aspects of the site.
- 8. *Reaching more experts* by arranging/getting involved at various topic-related activities in institutes and universities throughout world.

Donation could not be a part of a planned business, agree; but if some people are interested to do that; the undefined amount of finance could be used as a separate source designated strictly only for Stackexchange question and answer.

The fact that SE is now [NOT in desperate need](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/01/20/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/) of help (as said by user@PatrickHoffman); could be mentioned to the donors on the donation page; with warning of not to put any sort of pressure to the donors' own/ familial financial condition.