# Why could Stack Exchange block someone just for visiting 64 or more tags on tagoverflow?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, throttling

On [this](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368/tag-map-biology-se) question at [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) - [meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/), I found the following link:

http://p.migdal.pl/tagoverflow/?site=biology&size=32, noted as TagOvwrflow.

The site shows the following dialog box.

[image: Screenshot]

I could not understand; if I see 64 or more tags at a time; why will the site block me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you make too many requests to the SE servers in a very short time, you will be temporarily blocked. This is just a defense mechanism, and it applies to all users, even moderators and employees.

I suspect that this tool simply didn't implement any rate-limiting, and 64 might be too many requests if they're not throttled.

Comment: Indeed, SO indicates with the `backoff` field that you should sleep for a while before the next request. If you don't listen, you will be blocked (at least for a small time).

Comment: that means this is for avoid a slow-down or hang of network?

Comment: Yes, to prevent a single app to pull down the entire API (which the site and the mobile apps depend on too).